# Prettify Jinja2 Template

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I have a Jinja2 [template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29704737/jinja2-templating-boolean-variables-cleanly/29704917#29704917) that I'd like to use, but can't in conjunction with prettifying the code. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17124365/tidy-for-jinja2-templates) has been asked before, but that hasn't had an answer in almost 2 years, so perhaps there's an answer out there now.

```
<select id="example-getting-started" name="test" multiple="multiple">
   {% for k in pizza_dict %}
      <option value="{{ k }}" {% if pizza_dict[k] %}selected{% endif %}>{{ k }}</option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```

BeautifulSoup and lxml will "prettify" this code to:

```
<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple" name="test"> 
{% for k in pizza_dict %} 
    <option endif="" if="" pizza_dict="" value="{{ k }}"> {{ k }} </option> 
{% endfor %} </select>
```

which will destroy the code's function.

Comment: Jinja templates aren't xml so I wouldn't expect an xml prettifier to work.

Comment: You could try to use BeautifulSoup. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150108/python-how-to-pretty-print-html-into-a-file) answer. Also read [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pocoo-libs/s8CKOjz8J_0) topic.

Comment: @doru I demonstrated in my question that beautifulsoup and lxml both don't work.

Comment: As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50099477/9704865), I use the [atom-beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify "atom-beautify") package for the [Atom](https://atom.io/ "Atom") text editor when developing Flask/Jinja2 applications. The formatted templates look really neat.

Comment: @Nimrod thanks, that’s a great solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VSOT (see [Rodrigo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67706212/5712053)) seems to be unmaintained, but they recommend two alternatives:

- djLint (full formatting): https://djlint.com/ (GitHub: https://github.com/Riverside-Healthcare/djLint)
- djhtml (only indentation): https://github.com/rtts/djhtml

Answer (score 2):

Recently I was seeking for some tool for autoformatting and found the VSOT: https://pypi.org/project/vsot/